# Ubuntu Server is working but is unable to run applications

Tags: server

Memory is working 70% but it sometimes reaches 100%. When this happens nothing runs, not even the web browser. Does this mean format and reinstall?

[image: CPU 100% memory 70%]

Comment: Click on the other tabs in system monitor and find the program causing this issue. Then end the program with system monitor

Comment: Format and reinstall won't help ;-)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.